# async void when overriding

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm aware of the evils of `async void` methods but am not entirely sure of the best way of over coming the problem when overriding methods.

Say, I have the following code:

```
protected override async void PageRefreshed()
{
    BoundDataField = await LoadDataFromWeb();
}
```

I know this is a really bad thing to do, but what is the best solution for this?

1. `LoadDataFromWeb().ContinueWith(r => BoundDateField = r.Result);`
2. `Task.Run(async ()=> await LoadDataFromWeb())).Wait;`
3. `LoadDataFromWeb().Wait`
4. `BoundDataField = LoadDataFromWeb.Result`

I'm pretty sure that 3 & 4 are real no nos as they will be blocking the UI thread.  Is there another solution I have missed?

Comment: Can you change the source code of the base class?

Comment: No, base class is  from a nuget library

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm pretty sure that 3 & 4 are real no nos as they will be blocking the UI thread.

Not just blocking, but [quite possibly deadlocking](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), too.

> Is there another solution I have missed?

What you're trying to do is asynchronously retrieve the value of a data-bound property. I cover this in detail in my [MSDN article on asynchronous data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx).

First, the central thing to recognize is that this is impossible, as written. There are two conflicting requirements:

- The computer must display something immediately.
- You need to get the data to display, and this will take time.

So, you'll need to compromise:

- The computer gets some placeholder data or a spinner or something to display immediately.
- You update the display with the real data when it arrives.

Put this way, the code is more straightforward:

```
protected override async void PageRefreshed()
{
  BoundDataField = "placeholder"; // synchronous immediate placeholder data
  BoundDataField = await LoadDataFromWeb(); // asynchronous update
}
```

or:

```
protected override async void PageRefreshed()
{
  // Synchronously show spinner
  IsBusy = true;

  // Asynchronously load data and then hide spinner
  BoundDataField = await LoadDataFromWeb();
  IsBusy = false;
}
```

Note that this simple solution is not handling errors well and also doesn't handle multiple "refreshing"s possibly updating that field out of order. A more advanced approach is to use something like [my `NotifyTask<T>` type](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Async/blob/master/src/Nito.Mvvm.Async/NotifyTask.cs) from the `Nito.Mvvm.Async` NuGet package:

```
protected override void PageRefreshed()
{
  BoundDataField = NotifyTask<TData>.Create(LoadDataFromWeb());
}
```

This approach requires updates to your data binding code as well; `BoundDataField.Result` is now the actual data value, and `BoundDataField.IsNotCompleted`, `BoundDataField.IsFaulted`, and other properties can be used to have your data binding respond to in-progress or faulted states.

Comment: Third solution would probably be better as its the only one that overcomes the  `async void` problem.  Although will it give me more than using a continuewith (opt 1)?

Comment: I don't see an `async void` problem here; `async void` is for events or event-like notifications, and (I assume) `PageRefreshed` is an event-like notification, so `async void` would be appropriate. `ContinueWith` is not a viable option - it's just a lower-level implementation of your existing code.

Comment: One of the issues I understand there to be with `async void` is that if `LoadDatFromWeb` throws an exception I'll never know - but a least with the `ContinueWith` I'll be able to check if the task has faulted?

Comment: You'll know. Exceptions thrown from `async void` methods have a tendency to crash the process. [What actually happens](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) is they raise the exception directly on the `SynchronizationContext` that was current at the beginning of the `async void` method. Some people call `async void` "fire and forget", but not me - I call them "fire and crash".

Comment: So a standard try catch will overcome that?  Thanks for your responses @stephen - been very insightful. :-)

Comment: With `NotifyTask<T>`, exceptions are captured and used to update data-bound properties; with `async void`, yes, you will need a `try`/`catch` to handle exceptions when you're still *within* the `async void` method.